# Proof of Jensen's inequality using simple functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, inequality

Let $(X,M,\mu)$ be a measure space such that $\mu(X)=1$, $f$ be a real-valued measurable function with its integral on $X$ finite. $f$ is bounded by the open segment $(a,b)$ and $\phi$ is convex on $(a,b)$. Then $$\phi\int_Xf \,du \leq\int_X\phi\circ f\, du$$

I believe if the inf $f > a$ such that $f(x)\in[c,b)$ for some $c>a$, then by a similar construction as in Rudin's theorem 1.17, we can get a sequence of simple functions {$s_n$} such that $c\leq s_1\leq s_2\leq...\leq f$ and $lim_{n\to\infty}s_n=f$.
Consider any simple function $s_n$ where {$\alpha_i$} is the set of values taken by $s_n$ on $X$ and $A_i = $ {$x:s_n(x)=\alpha_i$}. $$\int_Xs_n\,d\mu=\sum_i\alpha_i\mu(A_i)$$

Then by the finite version of Jenson's theorem we get $$\phi(\sum_i\alpha_i\mu(A_i))\leq \sum_i\phi(\alpha_i)\mu(A_i)$$
Hence $\phi\int_Xs_n\,d\mu\leq \int_X\phi\circ s_n\,d\mu$.
Using the dominated convergence theorem we then have the desired inequality. I was wondering if this can changed to fit the general case where inf $f$ = $a$?